What terminal supports the most platforms?
Like "Any cross-platform email client?", I want a terminal which I can use on AOSP 14, Windows 11, and standard Linux-based OSes (like Fedora 40/Rawhide, openSUSE Tumbleweed, and postmarketOS Edge). That is my sole requirement.

If I learn of any, I'll use this Meta answer as my guidelines for how to submit answers.

https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/n3h8ez/best_cross_platform_terminal_client/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button also discusses this.

For WindTerm:
Supported

Windows
As demonstrated by https://github.com/kingToolbox/WindTerm/releases/download/2.6.0/WindTerm_2.6.1_Windows_Portable_x86_64.zip

macOS
As demonstrated by https://github.com/kingToolbox/WindTerm/releases/download/2.6.0/WindTerm_2.6.1_Mac_Portable_x86_64.dmg

Linux
As demonstrated by https://github.com/kingToolbox/WindTerm/releases/download/2.6.0/WindTerm_2.6.1_Linux_Portable_x86_64.tar.gz


Unsupported

AOSP
AOSP isn't yet compiled for, but the lead developer intends to support it soon, as https://github.com/kingToolbox/WindTerm/issues/849#issuecomment-1169578952 explains.

WASM
There is no indication that support is desired or expected.



Contour works on Linux (except for Android), Mac, FreeBSD, and Windows.

Thanks for this. That's the best yet. I've requested https://github.com/contour-terminal/contour/issues/1506#issue-2304591100 for AOSP support.

For Alacritty:
Supported

Windows
As demonstrated by https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/blob/05eb40a0b702d3db7575df5a8f7264a346d814d3/manifests/a/Alacritty/Alacritty/0.13.2/Alacritty.Alacritty.installer.yaml#L23

macOS
As demonstrated by https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/releases/download/v0.13.2/Alacritty-v0.13.2.dmg

Linux
As demonstrated by https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/rust-alacritty/alacritty/


Unsupported

AOSP
Unfortunately, it doesn't support AOSP, per https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/7121#issuecomment-1698248434.

WASM
Despite it being built upon the technology, this isn't desired by the maintenance team, as https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/7985#event-12835140916 demonstrates.



For Warp:
Supported

macOS
As demonstrated by https://github.com/warpdotdev/Warp/blob/e37f458cf274e8452bbf7eee61fe805db610d23e/README.md?plain=1#L31

Linux
As demonstrated by https://github.com/warpdotdev/Warp/issues/120#event-12221569061


Unsupported

Windows
Although it doesn't support Windows yet, the developers intend to, as https://github.com/warpdotdev/Warp/issues/204#issuecomment-2043469323 demonstrates.

AOSP
Although https://github.com/warpdotdev/Warp/issues/3328#issue-1794527007 has gained significant support, there is no response from the maintainers.

WASM
As https://github.com/warpdotdev/Warp/blob/e37f458cf274e8452bbf7eee61fe805db610d23e/README.md?plain=1#L35 states, support is planned. However, it doesn't appear to be tracked anywhere.


